# My button used to work -- but now it doesn't

Tags: javascript, button

I have this simple button set up on my page, which I'm going to put a different function into it as I work. But I can't get it to bring up the alert. It was working before, and not sure what's wrong now. Can someone help please?

```
function sortbutton()
{
    var button = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    var text = document.createTextNode("Click To Sort");
    button.appendChild(text);
    document.body.appendChild(button);
    button.onclick = function selection()   
    {
        alert("test");
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you executing your function, `sortbutton();`?

Comment: This code looks ok, so check if it's being called

Comment: What is the browser console reporting?

Comment: Yes, I'm executing the sortbutton(); function in my main function. The button loads, but when I click, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Have you disabled the popped-up alert in your browser? If so, you need to restart your browser again.

Comment: That was one of the stupidest things I could have overlooked -- you were right -- alerts were disabled. I've been working on this for too long. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested it and it worked fine. Perhaps you should execute sortbutton() after the document has been loaded.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<body>
   <script>
   function sortbutton(){
      var button = document.createElement("button");
      var text = document.createTextNode("Click To Sort");
      button.appendChild(text);
      document.body.appendChild(button);
      button.onclick = function selection()   {
         alert("test");
      }
   }
   sortbutton();
   </script>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

That was one of the stupidest things I could have overlooked -- you were right -- alerts were disabled. I've been working on this for too long. Thanks!